# Unable to inject ILogger into classes using Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have setup the logger in autofac configuration but the logger is not getting injected in the controller or other classes.

```
builder.RegisterType<SerilogLogger>()
                .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new NamedParameter("connectionString", azureConnectionString),
                    new NamedParameter("azureTableName", azureTableName),
                })
                .As<ILogger>().SingleInstance();
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private ILogger logger;

    public HomeController(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }
}
```

I need to explicitly access the logger. Any ideas?

Exception Details

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Exception is straight forward, seems to be problem with my autofac config.

Comment: Do you get an exception? If so, please add the complete exception details to your question.

Comment: Is the ILogger interface you registered with Autofac literally the same one you have in the constructor? There are a lot of ILogger interfaces out there.

Comment: ILogger is an interface I have written to facade over Nlog and Serilog.

Comment: @TravisIllig Even if the `ILogger`s were different ones, Autofac would throw with a different message if it was correctly wired up, right?

Comment: Nope. If you registered the wrong type of logger then all Autofac knows is it can't satisfy the parameter so you'll get a "no parameterless constructor" error. It matches on type, not name.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange that you tagged your question with `asp.net-web-api2`, yet your code sample seems to use ASP.NET MVC.

I can see two things happening here:

- You didn't [register the controllers](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#register-controllers) in your container
- and/or you didn't [set the `DependencyResolver`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#set-the-dependency-resolver) to use your Autofac container, which means the default controller activator is in charge of newing up your controllers, and it can only do so for controllers that have a default - parameterless - constructor

Comment: Yeah, i was just testing with HomeController. ILogger is not getting injected in any other classes either. I have the dependencyresolver set...all other dependencies get injected as expected.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your comment. You were just testing with an ASP.NET MVC `HomeController` but apart from this, are you using ASP.NET Web API? If so, did you set the [ASP.NET Web API-specific `DependencyResolver`](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#set-the-dependency-resolver)?

Comment: Seems to be working everywhere except HomeController which it wasn't before. I don't actually need HomeController...thanks for your help.